# Can I use the Wi-Fi logo on a website?

Tags: internet, branding

Despite reading [Wi-Fi alliance style guide](https://www.wi-fi.org/download.php?file=/sites/default/files/private/Wi-Fi_Alliance_Brand_Style_Guide_201907.pdf), I don't understand whether I can use the Wi-Fi logotype on my website. The style guide seems to target the producers of Wi-Fi equipment only; my case is different.

More precisely, I have a web page which, among others, explains how to configure a device to access a specific Wi-Fi access point. In order for the users to easily identify that the page talks about Wi-Fi, I want to include the Wi-Fi logotype. Not the one with “Certified” on it; just the plain one.

Can I do it? Or is Wi-Fi logotype reserved exclusively to the hardware which connects through Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use a trademarked logo on a product you would need permission of the trademark owner's, just like with any other trademark.  However, you don't need permission to use a trademark outside the context of trade and commerce.  For example, despite the fact that the Wi-Fi Alliance's own name is a trademark, you didn't need permission to use it in your question.  Similarly Wikipedia didn't need permission to use the Wi-Fi Alliance's logo in their [article on the organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Alliance):

> [image]

However, given your stated use, you'd be better served by not using the Wi-Fi logo on your web page. This logo is designed to be used to identify products that have been certified by Wi-Fi Alliance, not as a generic Wi-Fi symbol.  Whether your page would infringe on the trademark or not, the use of logo could cause confusion and not send the message you're intending.

Comment: What is the role of "confusion" in a legal analysis of trademark infringement? "Whether or not" is not independent of "confusion".

Comment: @user6726  That would be another question. The original poster doesn't want to cause confusion so removing it is a good idea for that reason alone.

Comment: But the question is not asking for advice on what to do (that's off-topic), it's asking what the law is – infringement is the heart of the question. Infringement is legally defined in terms of confusability and similar concept: it's not just "in trade and commerce".

Comment: @user6726 You're asking a different question than the original poster.

Comment: @user6726 Confusion is literally the primary concern of trademark law. Trademarks don't exist to protect creativity or innovation, they exist to prevent confusion about who's behind something.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be a member of the alliance to use them. There are a lot of other "WiFi" symbols that are pretty universally recognized, I'd use one of those in the free/public domain. You could also email them or otherwise contact them for special permission to use it on your website.